# Extracting numbers with decimals from large strings in R

Tags: r, regex, gsub, stringr

I would like to extract numbers from this vector composed of 15 observations:

```
rs <- c("\n        \n            \n        \n\n        \n    \n        \n\n    \n        \n        \n            \n                \n            \n        \n        \n            \n                \n                    4.0\n                    (1 rating)\n                \n                \n                    \n                        Course Ratings are calculated from individual students’ ratings and a variety of other signals, like age of rating and reliability, to ensure that they reflect course quality fairly and accurately.\n                    \n                \n            \n        \n        \n    \n\n\n    \n    \n        \n\n    \n        \n            9 students enrolled\n        \n    \n\n\n    \n\n    ", 
"\n        \n            \n        \n\n        \n    \n        \n\n    \n        \n        \n            \n                \n            \n        \n        \n            \n                \n                    4.7\n                    (4 ratings)\n                \n                \n                    \n                        Course Ratings are calculated from individual students’ ratings and a variety of other signals, like age of rating and reliability, to ensure that they reflect course quality fairly and accurately.\n                    \n                \n            \n        \n        \n    \n\n\n    \n    \n        \n\n    \n        \n            34 students enrolled\n        \n    \n\n\n    \n\n    ", 
"\n        \n            \n        \n\n        \n    \n        \n\n    \n        \n        \n            \n                \n            \n        \n        \n            \n                \n                    3.1\n                    (5 ratings)\n                \n                \n                    \n                        Course Ratings are calculated from individual students’ ratings and a variety of other signals, like age of rating and reliability, to ensure that they reflect course quality fairly and accurately.\n                    \n                \n            \n        \n        \n    \n\n\n    \n    \n        \n\n    \n        \n            22 students enrolled\n        \n    \n\n\n    \n\n    ", 
"\n        \n            \n        \n\n        \n    \n        \n\n    \n        \n        \n            \n                \n            \n        \n        \n            \n                \n                    2.4\n                    (14 ratings)\n                \n                \n                    \n                        Course Ratings are calculated from individual students’ ratings and a variety of other signals, like age of rating and reliability, to ensure that they reflect course quality fairly and accurately.\n                    \n                \n            \n        \n        \n    \n\n\n    \n    \n        \n\n    \n        \n            2,106 students enrolled\n        \n    \n\n\n    \n\n    ", 
"\n        \n            \n        \n\n        \n    \n        \n\n    \n        \n        \n            \n                \n            \n        \n        \n            \n                \n                    4.3\n                    (67 ratings)\n                \n                \n                    \n                        Course Ratings are calculated from individual students’ ratings and a variety of other signals, like age of rating and reliability, to ensure that they reflect course quality fairly and accurately.\n                    \n                \n            \n        \n        \n    \n\n\n    \n    \n        \n\n    \n        \n            1,287 students enrolled\n        \n    \n\n\n    \n\n    ", 
"\n        \n            \n        \n\n        \n    \n        \n\n    \n        \n        \n            \n                \n            \n        \n        \n            \n                \n                    4.6\n                    (3 ratings)\n                \n                \n                    \n                        Course Ratings are calculated from individual students’ ratings and a variety of other signals, like age of rating and reliability, to ensure that they reflect course quality fairly and accurately.\n                    \n                \n            \n        \n        \n    \n\n\n    \n    \n        \n\n    \n        \n            30 students enrolled\n        \n    \n\n\n    \n\n    ", 
"\n        \n            \n                \n                    \n\n    \n        New\n    \n\n\n                \n\n            \n        \n\n        \n    \n        \n\n    \n        \n        \n            \n                \n            \n        \n        \n            \n                \n                    0.0\n                    (0 ratings)\n                \n                \n                    \n                        Course Ratings are calculated from individual students’ ratings and a variety of other signals, like age of rating and reliability, to ensure that they reflect course quality fairly and accurately.\n                    \n                \n            \n        \n        \n    \n\n\n    \n    \n        \n\n    \n        \n            8 students enrolled\n        \n    \n\n\n    \n\n    ", 
"\n        \n            \n                \n                    \n\n    \n        Highest Rated\n    \n\n\n                \n            \n        \n\n        \n    \n        \n\n    \n        \n        \n            \n                \n            \n        \n        \n            \n                \n                    4.6\n                    (12 ratings)\n                \n                \n                    \n                        Course Ratings are calculated from individual students’ ratings and a variety of other signals, like age of rating and reliability, to ensure that they reflect course quality fairly and accurately.\n                    \n                \n            \n        \n        \n    \n\n\n    \n    \n        \n\n    \n        \n            42 students enrolled\n        \n    \n\n\n    \n\n    ", 
"\n        \n            \n        \n\n        \n    \n        \n\n    \n        \n        \n            \n                \n            \n        \n        \n            \n                \n                    4.4\n                    (6 ratings)\n                \n                \n                    \n                        Course Ratings are calculated from individual students’ ratings and a variety of other signals, like age of rating and reliability, to ensure that they reflect course quality fairly and accurately.\n                    \n                \n            \n        \n        \n    \n\n\n    \n    \n        \n\n    \n        \n            41 students enrolled\n        \n    \n\n\n    \n\n    ", 
"\n        \n            \n        \n\n        \n    \n        \n\n    \n        \n        \n            \n                \n            \n        \n        \n            \n                \n                    4.2\n                    (12 ratings)\n                \n                \n                    \n                        Course Ratings are calculated from individual students’ ratings and a variety of other signals, like age of rating and reliability, to ensure that they reflect course quality fairly and accurately.\n                    \n                \n            \n        \n        \n    \n\n\n    \n    \n        \n\n    \n        \n            115 students enrolled\n        \n    \n\n\n    \n\n    ", 
"\n        \n            \n        \n\n        \n    \n        \n\n    \n        \n        \n            \n                \n            \n        \n        \n            \n                \n                    4.8\n                    (6 ratings)\n                \n                \n                    \n                        Course Ratings are calculated from individual students’ ratings and a variety of other signals, like age of rating and reliability, to ensure that they reflect course quality fairly and accurately.\n                    \n                \n            \n        \n        \n    \n\n\n    \n    \n        \n\n    \n        \n            25 students enrolled\n        \n    \n\n\n    \n\n    ", 
"\n        \n            \n        \n\n        \n    \n        \n\n    \n        \n        \n            \n                \n            \n        \n        \n            \n                \n                    4.6\n                    (19 ratings)\n                \n                \n                    \n                        Course Ratings are calculated from individual students’ ratings and a variety of other signals, like age of rating and reliability, to ensure that they reflect course quality fairly and accurately.\n                    \n                \n            \n        \n        \n    \n\n\n    \n    \n        \n\n    \n        \n            151 students enrolled\n        \n    \n\n\n    \n\n    ", 
"\n        \n            \n        \n\n        \n    \n        \n\n    \n        \n        \n            \n                \n            \n        \n        \n            \n                \n                    4.5\n                    (10 ratings)\n                \n                \n                    \n                        Course Ratings are calculated from individual students’ ratings and a variety of other signals, like age of rating and reliability, to ensure that they reflect course quality fairly and accurately.\n                    \n                \n            \n        \n        \n    \n\n\n    \n    \n        \n\n    \n        \n            385 students enrolled\n        \n    \n\n\n    \n\n    ", 
"\n        \n            \n        \n\n        \n    \n        \n\n    \n        \n        \n            \n                \n            \n        \n        \n            \n                \n                    4.8\n                    (166 ratings)\n                \n                \n                    \n                        Course Ratings are calculated from individual students’ ratings and a variety of other signals, like age of rating and reliability, to ensure that they reflect course quality fairly and accurately.\n                    \n                \n            \n        \n        \n    \n\n\n    \n    \n        \n\n    \n        \n            754 students enrolled\n        \n    \n\n\n    \n\n    ", 
"\n        \n            \n        \n\n        \n    \n        \n\n    \n        \n        \n            \n                \n            \n        \n        \n            \n                \n                    3.6\n                    (34 ratings)\n                \n                \n                    \n                        Course Ratings are calculated from individual students’ ratings and a variety of other signals, like age of rating and reliability, to ensure that they reflect course quality fairly and accurately.\n                    \n                \n            \n        \n        \n    \n\n\n    \n    \n        \n\n    \n        \n            3,396 students enrolled\n        \n    \n\n\n    \n\n    "
)
```

As you can see, there are 15 objects very long and dirt. However, a pattern inside of them is easily identifiable. Every object is composed of 3 numbers (with the example of the first observation):

- Rating: from 0 to 5. For instance, `4.0`
- Number of ratings. For instance `(1 rating)`
- Enrolled students. For instance `9 students enrolled`.

I would like to extract all these numerical values and create a dataframe with 3 columns, each for each variable.

I've been checking several questions here in Stackoverflow, mainly focused on the use of `gsub()` of the package `stringr`. However, I don't get to find the key solution to my problem.

UPDATE

These are the codes I tried:

```
as.numeric(str_extract(rs, "[0-9]+"))
as.numeric(str_extract(rs, "[0-9]+")[[1]])
as.numeric(str_extract(rs, "(?<=\\()[0-9]+(?=\\))"))
as.numeric(sapply(strsplit(rs, " "), "[[", 1))
```

Comment: If there is any regularity to your input file, you should ideally tell us what that might be.

Comment: so, you checked some packages. can you show some of the work that failed to provide the desired result? it may just be a regex that needs tweaking. i mean, you certainly did that and aren't just expecting folks to code up a solution for you for free, right?

Comment: In every observation there are three numbers. So the final output should be a dataframe with three columns and 15 rows with all those numbers. I updated the question with some of my tries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `extract` from `tidyr`, we can do:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data.frame(rs, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>%
  extract(rs, c("Rating", "Number_of_ratings", "Students_enrolled"),
          "(?s)(\\d\\.\\d).*?(\\d+)\\s*ratings?.*?(\\d+(?:,\\d+)?)\\s*students enrolled", 
          convert = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(Students_enrolled = as.numeric(sub(",", "", Students_enrolled)))
```

**Output:**

```
   Rating Number_of_ratings Students_enrolled
1     4.0                 1                 9
2     4.7                 4                34
3     3.1                 5                22
4     2.4                14              2106
5     4.3                67              1287
6     4.6                 3                30
7     0.0                 0                 8
8     4.6                12                42
9     4.4                 6                41
10    4.2                12               115
11    4.8                 6                25
12    4.6                19               151
13    4.5                10               385
14    4.8               166               754
15    3.6                34              3396
```

**Notes:**

The regular expression looks complicated, but it's really not. What `extract` does is it extracts the match from each capture group (things surrounded by parentheses) and turn them into its own column.

1. `(?s)` is a modifier which turns on the "DOTALL" mode. This allows the dot `.` to also match newline characters.
2. `(\\d\\.\\d)` matches the `Rating` pattern
3. `(\\d+)\\s*ratings` matches the `Number_of_ratings` pattern but only extracts the digits `(\\d+)`
4. `(\\d+(?:,\\d+)?)\\s*students enrolled` matches the `Students_enrolled` pattern, but only extracts the "digits with or without comma" pattern
5. `convert = TRUE` attempts to convert the resulting columns to their best data type, but since there are commas in `Students_enrolled`, an extra `mutate` is needed to convert it to numeric

Normally, `extract` throws an error if the number of capture groups is not equal to the number of output columns, but since modifiers `(?s)` and non-capturing groups `(?:...)` are not considered capture groups, the capture group count matches the column count.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I am getting an error when using your code: `Error: var must evaluate to a single number or a column name, not a character vector`. Any idea?

Comment: @antecessor My bad, I missed a step where I first store `rs` in a `data.frame` See my edits

Answer (score 3):

1-dependency base R solution with a commented, readable regex.

This also shows how to clean up the text for processing (in a way that you can re-use).

```
library(stringi)

do.call(
  rbind.data.frame,
  lapply(
    stri_match_all_regex(
      stri_replace_all_regex(
        stri_trim_both(rs),             # clean up outer spaces
        "[[:blank:][:space:]]+", " "    # clean up inner spaces
      ),
      "
([[:digit:]\\.]+)[[:space:]]+\\(([[:digit:],]+)[[:space:]]+rating[s]*\\)# pick up the rating and total number of ratings
[^[:digit:]]*([[:digit:],]+)[[:space:]]+student[s]*[[:space:]]+enrolled                          # pick up the number of students enrolled
",
      opts_regex = stri_opts_regex(comments = TRUE),
    ),
    function(x) {
      as.list(
        setNames(
          x[2:4], c("rating", "n_ratings", "enrolled")
        ),
        stringsAsFactors = FALSE
      )
    }
  )
)
```

Resulting in:

```
##    rating n_ratings enrolled
## 2     4.0         1        9
## 21    4.7         4       34
## 3     3.1         5       22
## 4     2.4        14    2,106
## 5     4.3        67    1,287
## 6     4.6         3       30
## 7     0.0         0        8
## 8     4.6        12       42
## 9     4.4         6       41
## 10    4.2        12      115
## 11    4.8         6       25
## 12    4.6        19      151
## 13    4.5        10      385
## 14    4.8       166      754
## 15    3.6        34    3,396
```

Turning ^^ into #'s is pretty basic after that.

Answer (score 2):

So your issue is that it doesn't see the "." as a part of a number since it is in a string. So you need to explicitly find the numbers and decimal point.

```
Rating <- as.numeric(str_extract(rs, "[0-9]\\.[0-9]"))
NRatings <- str_extract(rs, "\\([0-9]") %>% str_replace("\\(","") %>% as.numeric()
```

I will let you figure out the last one based on these examples ;)

Comment: You can also just use a lookbehind for `NRatings`: `str_extract(rs, "(?<=\\()[0-9]+")`